# for loop to while loop + additional condition

Tags: c, loops

I have a loop similar to this.

```
int total1, total2;
for (total1 = fsize(myfile);;) {
    total2 = fsize(myfile);
    ...
    ...
    total1 = total2;
}
```

What I would like to do is to convert this to a `while` loop and check for an extra condition before ending the loop.

I would like to do something like this:

```
while((total1 = fsize(myfile)) && input = getch() != 'Q') {
    total2 = fsize(myfile);
    ...
    total1 = total2;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: go right ahead.   You should parenthesize `((input = getch())!='Q')`.

Comment: Actually for some reason, it does not get into the loop... so I'm not quite sure if I'm doing the while loop right or not.

Comment: Your `for` loop has no termination condition. Is there a `break`, `goto`, or `return` inside it or is it meant to be an infinite loop?

Comment: is meant to be a infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant

```
while((total1 == fsize(myfile)) && ((input = getch()) != 'Q')) {
    total2 = fsize(myfile);
    ...
    total1 = total2;
}
```

Mind those operators = is assignment == is comparison

Comment: And perhaps you meant not to change the second `=` to `==`.

Comment: Its almost impossible to tell exactly what he meant without a lot more context.

Answer (score 0):

The 'initialization' part of the for loop `total1=fsize(myfile)` has become part of the condition tested in your while loop. Is that what you intended??

Are you sure you didn't want this...

```
total1 = fsize(myfile);

while((input = getch()) != 'Q') {
  total2 = fsize(myfile);
  ...
  total1 = total2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initializer in a for loop is only performed once. The `while` equivalent of

```
for (total1 = fsize(myfile);;) {
```

is

```
total1 = fsize(myfile);
while (1) {
```

You mention adding the condition `input = getch() != 'Q'`.

Note that assignment (`=`) has lower priority than comparison (`!=`), so to assign `getch()` to `input` and check that the character wasn't a `Q` you need parenthesis around the assignement:

```
total1 = fsize(myfile);
while ((input = getch()) != 'Q') {
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a for:

```
for(total1 = fsize(myfile); (input = getch()) != 'Q';) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can *always* use a "for" in place of a while. Just change "while" to "for" and put semicolons just before and after the condition.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Of course. I was trying to guess the answer the OP was looking for